# Hide some coefficients in regression summary while still returning call, r-squared and other summary output

Tags: r, output, regression, summary, dummy-variable

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610821/r-hide-dummies-output/29612376#) however I am interested in returning all the other outputs, not just coefficients. Here is sample code to make my question clearer.

```
data=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50*50),50,50))
summary(lm(data[,1]~.-data[,1],data=data))
```

I want to only output say the first 5 coefficients. I know I can just do that with
`summary(lm(data[,1]~.-data[,1],data=data))$coeff[1:5,]`, but that would get rid of all the other outputs I want. I also know I can get each output individually, I just want to know if there is a succicnt way of writing a one liner and cutting out variables that I do not want reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the coefficients you want with a slight modification to the `print.summary.lm` function, which is the internal function that R uses to output the summary results for a `summary.lm` object.

First, get the code for the function as follows:

```
getAnywhere(print.summary.lm)
```

Then, we need to figure out where the coefficient table is extracted and subset it to the rows we want. We'll add a new `my.rows` argument to the function and then subset to those rows when we extract the coefficient table. The code for the modified function is at the end of this answer.

Now, compare the standard summary with our new summary. First I'll create a model with real data (The model you provided isn't specified properly. Looks like what you intended was `lm(V1 ~ ., data=data)`, but even then there are no residual degrees of freedom, so I thought I'd demonstrate with a real data set.):

```
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl + vs + am, data=mtcars)
```

**Standard summary:**

```
summary(m1)
```

> ```
> Call:
>   lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl + vs + am, data = mtcars)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -3.6729 -1.6583 -0.4297  1.3307  5.4688 
>
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) 33.24160    5.48527   6.060 2.11e-06 ***
> wt          -2.54332    0.93506  -2.720   0.0115 *  
> hp          -0.02589    0.01387  -1.866   0.0733 .  
> cyl         -0.40179    0.79364  -0.506   0.6169    
> vs           1.17067    1.81283   0.646   0.5241    
> am           1.97575    1.64825   1.199   0.2415    
> ---
>   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 2.537 on 26 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8514,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8228 
> F-statistic:  29.8 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 5.571e-10
> ```

**New summary with only the coefficients we choose:**

Note that we need to call `summary` on the model first, since `my.summary.lm` is expecting the summary object, not the model object itself.

```
my.summary.lm(summary(m1), my.rows=2:4)
```

Rather than selecting coefficients by index, you might prefer to select by name:

```
my.summary.lm(summary(m1), my.rows=grep("wt|hp|cyl", names(coef(m1))))
```

> ```
> Call:
>   lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl + vs + am, data = mtcars)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -3.6729 -1.6583 -0.4297  1.3307  5.4688 
>
> Coefficients:
>     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
> wt  -2.54332    0.93506  -2.720   0.0115 *
> hp  -0.02589    0.01387  -1.866   0.0733 .
> cyl -0.40179    0.79364  -0.506   0.6169  
> ---
>   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 2.537 on 26 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.8514,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8228 
> F-statistic:  29.8 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 5.571e-10
> ```

And here's the function. I've made only two changes to the original function, both of which are marked with inline comments. The first change is the additional `my.rows` argument. The second is in the line that begins `coefs <-`:

```
my.summary.lm = function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), 
                       symbolic.cor = x$symbolic.cor, 
                       signif.stars = getOption("show.signif.stars"), 
                       my.rows, ...)                     # NOTE NEW my.rows ARGUMENT
{
  cat("\nCall:\n", paste(deparse(x$call), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), 
      "\n\n", sep = "")
  resid <- x$residuals
  df <- x$df
  rdf <- df[2L]
  cat(if (!is.null(x$weights) && diff(range(x$weights))) 
    "Weighted ", "Residuals:\n", sep = "")
  if (rdf > 5L) {
    nam <- c("Min", "1Q", "Median", "3Q", "Max")
    rq <- if (length(dim(resid)) == 2L) 
      structure(apply(t(resid), 1L, quantile), dimnames = list(nam, 
                                                               dimnames(resid)[[2L]]))
    else {
      zz <- zapsmall(quantile(resid), digits + 1L)
      structure(zz, names = nam)
    }
    print(rq, digits = digits, ...)
  }
  else if (rdf > 0L) {
    print(resid, digits = digits, ...)
  }
  else {
    cat("ALL", df[1L], "residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!")
    cat("\n")
  }
  if (length(x$aliased) == 0L) {
    cat("\nNo Coefficients\n")
  }
  else {
    if (nsingular <- df[3L] - df[1L]) 
      cat("\nCoefficients: (", nsingular, " not defined because of singularities)\n", 
          sep = "")
    else cat("\nCoefficients:\n")
    coefs <- x$coefficients[my.rows,]                      # SUBSET my.rows
    if (!is.null(aliased <- x$aliased) && any(aliased)) {
      cn <- names(aliased)
      coefs <- matrix(NA, length(aliased), 4, dimnames = list(cn, 
                                                              colnames(coefs)))
      coefs[!aliased, ] <- x$coefficients
    }
    printCoefmat(coefs, digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars, 
                 na.print = "NA", ...)
  }
  cat("\nResidual standard error:", format(signif(x$sigma, 
                                                  digits)), "on", rdf, "degrees of freedom")
  cat("\n")
  if (nzchar(mess <- naprint(x$na.action))) 
    cat("  (", mess, ")\n", sep = "")
  if (!is.null(x$fstatistic)) {
    cat("Multiple R-squared: ", formatC(x$r.squared, digits = digits))
    cat(",\tAdjusted R-squared: ", formatC(x$adj.r.squared, 
                                           digits = digits), "\nF-statistic:", formatC(x$fstatistic[1L], 
                                                                                       digits = digits), "on", x$fstatistic[2L], "and", 
        x$fstatistic[3L], "DF,  p-value:", format.pval(pf(x$fstatistic[1L], 
                                                          x$fstatistic[2L], x$fstatistic[3L], lower.tail = FALSE), 
                                                       digits = digits))
    cat("\n")
  }
  correl <- x$correlation
  if (!is.null(correl)) {
    p <- NCOL(correl)
    if (p > 1L) {
      cat("\nCorrelation of Coefficients:\n")
      if (is.logical(symbolic.cor) && symbolic.cor) {
        print(symnum(correl, abbr.colnames = NULL))
      }
      else {
        correl <- format(round(correl, 2), nsmall = 2, 
                         digits = digits)
        correl[!lower.tri(correl)] <- ""
        print(correl[-1, -p, drop = FALSE], quote = FALSE)
      }
    }
  }
  cat("\n")
  invisible(x)
}
```

**UPDATE:** As I mentioned in my comment, you can roll your own summary function and set it up to work with whatever type of model summary objects you regularly use. In this case, we'll include `summary.lm` and `summary.plm` objects, which are the types of objects created when you run `summary` on `lm` and `plm` model objects, respectively.

First we need lm and plm model objects to work with:

```
# lm object
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl + vs + am, data=mtcars)

# plm object
library(plm)

# Example from plm help
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
```

Now we need a function to output the summary data we want. To create the code below, I just looked at what was in the list objects created by `summary(m1)` and `summary(zz)` (do `str(summary(m1))` and `str(summary(zz))` to see these) so I'd know where to get various elements of the summary objects (such as the `call` and the `residuals`). I also in some cases just directly copied code sections from the `print.summary.lm` and `print.summary.plm` functions.

The function below doesn't print everything that's included in the native summary functions, but should be enough to show you how to go about adding whatever elements you'd like in the output.

```
# Summary function that allows selection of which coefficients to include 
# in the coefficient table
# Works with summary.lm and summary.plm objects
my.summary = function(x, rows, digits=3) {

  # Print a few summary elements that are common to both lm and plm model summary objects
  cat("Call\n")
  print(x$call)
  cat("\nResiduals\n")
  print(summary(x$residuals))
  cat("\n")
  print(coef(x)[rows,])

  # Print elements unique to lm model summary objects
  if("summary.lm" %in% class(x)) {
    cat("\nResidual standard error:", round(x$sigma,3), "on", x$df[2], "degrees of freedom")
    cat(paste(c("\nF-statistic:", " on"," and"), round(x$fstatistic,2), collapse=""),
        "DF, p-value:",
        format.pval(pf(x$fstatistic[1L], x$fstatistic[2L], x$fstatistic[3L], 
                       lower.tail = FALSE), digits=digits))

  # Print elements unique to plm model summary objects  
  } else if ("summary.plm" %in% class(x)) {
    cat(paste("\nResidual Sum of Squares: ", signif(deviance(x), 
                                                  digits), "\n", sep = ""))
    fstat <- x$fstatistic
    if (names(fstat$statistic) == "F") {
      cat(paste("F-statistic: ", signif(fstat$statistic), " on ", 
                fstat$parameter["df1"], " and ", fstat$parameter["df2"], 
                " DF, p-value: ", format.pval(fstat$p.value, digits = digits), 
                "\n", sep = ""))
    }
    else {
      cat(paste("Chisq: ", signif(fstat$statistic), " on ", 
                fstat$parameter, " DF, p-value: ", format.pval(fstat$p.value, 
                                                               digits = digits), "\n", sep = ""))
    }
  }
}
```

Now run the function on an `lm` model and a `plm` model:

```
my.summary(summary(m1), 2:4)
```

> ```
> Call
> lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl + vs + am, data = mtcars)
>
> Residuals
>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
> -3.6730 -1.6580 -0.4297  0.0000  1.3310  5.4690 
>
>        Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
> wt  -2.54331718 0.93506164 -2.7199460 0.01148231
> hp  -0.02588661 0.01387176 -1.8661377 0.07334148
> cyl -0.40178727 0.79364098 -0.5062582 0.61694148
>
> Residual standard error: 2.537 on 26 degrees of freedom
> F-statistic: 29.8 on 5 and 26 DF, p-value: 5.57e-10
> ```

```
my.summary(summary(zz), 2:3)
```

> ```
> Call
> plm(formula = log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
>     data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"))
>
> Residuals
>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
> -0.120500 -0.023740 -0.002041  0.000000  0.018140  0.174700 
>
>           Estimate Std. Error  t-value      Pr(>|t|)
> log(pc)  0.2920069 0.02511967 11.62463  7.075069e-29
> log(emp) 0.7681595 0.03009174 25.52725 2.021455e-104
>
> Residual Sum of Squares: 1.11
> F-statistic: 3064.81 on 4 and 764 DF, p-value: <2e-16
> ```

I suppose if you really want to go all the way, you could take advantage of object orientation and write your own [generic function with methods](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) for each type of model you want to include.

Comment: Thank you. This works wonderfully for lm command, but does not seem to work when I use the plm package. 
`m1 = plm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris, index=c('Species'))`. If I were to run this based on this previous example
`my.summary.lm(summary(m1))` #this throws an error

Comment: That's because the `plm` package has it own function, `print.summary.plm` for printing model summaries to the console. You can create your own `my.summary.plm` function that modifies the `print.summary.plm` function in an analogous way to my answer. The disadvantage is that you need to do this separately for each type of model object that you want to print to the console. Another option is to create your own function that can grab the desired information from the various types of model summary objects that you usually work with and print them to the console.

Comment: See updated code for ideas on how to create your own function that will work with different types of model summary objects.

Comment: How can I do this with felm from the lfe package?

Comment: Run `getAnywhere(summary.felm)` to get the code for the summary method for `felm` objects. Then follows the steps in my answer above to customize `summary.felm` to meet your needs. If you don't understand some aspect of my answer, you can use the comments to ask for clarification. If you have a new issue not addressed by my answer, then feel free to ask a new question.